# Python Update Dictionary values to reference dataframes with the same name

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, nested

I have many dataframes with names such as 'ABC', 'XYZ'...

I also have a dictionary with keys, where each key has a list of 200 values which are the names of the dataframes i.e. ['ABC','XYZ',...]

I want to update this dictionary, so instead of containing the names of the dataframes, it contains the dataframes themselves as a nested dictionary.

THis will enable me to iterate over a specific key of the main dictionary dictionary, and access each of its 200 dataframes  by name

i.e. dictionary[key1][ABC] would print out the ABC dataframe.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the keys currently in this dictionary? / Where are your dataframes currently stored? You probably want something like this:

```
dfDict ={dfName: <df>} #assuming a bit here
newDict = {}
for key, value in oldDict.items():
    newDict[key] = { dfName:dfDict[dfName] for dfName in value }
```

Comment: Keys currently in the dictionary are date strings.  Dataframes are currently stored in another massive dictionary

Comment: I advise caution, the logic in this statement: `newDict[key] = { dfName:dfDict[dfName] for dfName in value }` will leave `newDict[key]` with only the last entry in the list `value`. It does not append to form a list in `newDict[key]`.

Comment: I believe it is a difference in interpretation of the question. My impression was that cwse wanted an ending data structure of: {date : { dfName : df, dfName2: df2, ... }. My answer doesn't return a list, just a nested dictionary.

Comment: @Kartik I think this method actually does the right thing in a shorter way, it doesn't require EVAL (which I read can have security issues and should be avoided).  Thank you both for your efforts here!

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough, use `eval`:

```
u, v, w, x, y, z = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
frames = {}
names = {'a' : ['u', 'v'],
         'b' : ['w', 'x'],
         'c' : ['y', 'z']}
for key in names:
    frames[key] = dict(zip(names[key], [eval(name) for name in names[key]]))
frames
# Output:
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [5, 6]}
```

Comment: Almost, I think OP wants to get {'a': {'1':1, '2':2} ... }

Comment: Yeah, @Boud, my oversight. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, struggling to understand it though.. where are the dataframes here?

Comment: think I got it..!

Comment: @cwse, Great! I planned to write an explanation when I saw your first comment, and now when I finally got around to doing it, seems like you sorted it out yourself. I just saved myself the tedium of creating `DataFrame`, and used `int` in my answer instead. Basically anything you can assign to a variable, can be extracted in this way. Even expressions such as `eval(x + y)` will work using the values in `x` and `y`, and in this case return 9.

Comment: Just wondering, is there a faster way than eval? Which I understand isnt that efficient?

Comment: Not that I know of, unfortunately. I haven't had the need to use `eval` for more than small tasks, hence I never looked to optimize it further.